# Indian English language prepositions

Tags: prepositions, subcontinental-english

What is difference between preposition here (In and To)?
Why we use : Israel ambassador *to* India.
Why don't we use : Israel ambassador *in* India.

Comment: If you want answers specific to accepted 'Indian English', romil, you need to use the _Indian-English_ tag.

Answer (score 4):

The use of "in" carries no particular connotation except that the ambassador resides in India, whereas the use of "to" refers the ambassador's assignation  which has been determined by his government as *to* India; he/she has been assigned/appointed to the occupation of  ambassadorship to/in India for Israel.

"To" is used much more frequently.

[image]

Comment: Right - not even permanent residence, just where they are right now, even. The "Israeli ambassador in India" could be the Israeli ambassador to the US or any other country, sent to India for the week for a specific purpose, or for that matter, there on vacation.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do we use : Israel ambassador to India.

If what you say is so, (in BE and AE we would say ***Israel's** ambassador to India**) then

**Israel** and **ambassador** are both noun phrases:

Noun1 + Noun2  - NP2 associated contextually with NP1

Israel + Ambassador  - The ambassador associated contextually with Israel

**to** is used because this is the same "to" as in "This is the road **to** Agra". **To** indicates destination.

Israel has sent an ambassador **to** India.